# Q: Recharts hide every other label?

Tags: recharts

Hiyas, I'm wondering if it's possible to render every other xAxis label in recharts?

I have a design I'm working from that has vertical grid lines on either side of an xAxis label. So, I'm using `<ReferenceLines>` in place of a `<CartesianGrid>`, and that seems to work well. However, I haven't found a way to render only some of the xAxis labels.

I could mutate the date coming into the chart, but then I lose the data-points `date` value in the `<Tooltip>` hover. Which if possible I'd like to keep.

---

Here's effectively what I have:

[image]

And here's what I'm aiming for:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a "way" by leveraging the `tickFormatter` attribute on `<XAxis />`. Albeit, the best approach would be for `tickFormatter` to return index like some of the other recharts components offer with `format`. However, for the time being I'm simply finding the index of a given xAxis label, from my dataset, and then checking if it's an even/odd number.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the `interval` attribute. This controls whether to show all or some of your xAxis labels. By default it is set to preserveEnd which auto calculates how many ticks to show.

If you want to show all ticks, you must set `interval=0`
Docs https://recharts.org/en-US/api/XAxis#interval